# Set Makefile variable before target dependency

Tags: makefile

I'm working on a Makefile for building one or all targets from a list `TARGETS` (in this example, RPMS for one or many architectures).

If the variable `TARGET` is given, that particular RPM is built.  If the variable `TARGET` is not set, the rule for each TARGET in TARGETS would be invoked, i.e.:

```
TARGETS = x86_64 i686
ifdef TARGET
all: $(TARGET)
else
all: $(TARGETS)
endif

<magical part:>
$(TARGETS): TARGET = $@: rpm

rpm:
  rpmbuild --target=$(TARGET) SPECS/foo.spec
```

I also tried:

```
TARGETS = x86_64 i686
ifdef TARGET
all: $(TARGET)
else
all: $(TARGETS)
endif

<magical part:>
$(TARGETS): TARGET = $@
$(TARGETS): rpm

rpm:
  rpmbuild --target=$(TARGET) SPECS/foo.spec
```

Can this be done, or would I be better off calling `make` anew for each target, e.g.:

```
TARGETS = x86_64 i686
ifdef TARGET
all: rpm
else
all: $(TARGETS)
endif

$(TARGETS):
  make TARGET=$@

rpm:
  rpmbuild --target=$(TARGET) SPECS/foo.spec
```

Ideal invocation would be `TARGET=x86_64 make` equivalent to `make x86_64`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure why you want to do this, but here's one way to do it:

```
TARGETS = a b c
ifdef TARGET
all: $(TARGET)
else
all: $(TARGETS)
endif

$(sort $(TARGETS) $(TARGET)):
    @echo $@
```

The `sort` function removes duplicates. If your `TARGET` is one of the elements in `TARGETS`, Make will complain about a duplication in the target list, unless you remove it.

Comment: The "why" is two-fold: 1) convenience for developers so they can invoke either way; 2) when `all` is `TARGETS` there's just one `make` invocation, not four, and when invoking with a specific target, say `make a`, there's also just the one `make` invocation

Comment: I should add: `TARGET` is used for more than `@echo $(TARGET)`, it actually is part of, and influences, other commands

Comment: @alkalinity: Perhaps you could edit your Question to show how you want to use `TARGET` in a way that `$@` could not be; it's starting to sound like the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).